# Find language for a regular expression through derivation rule

Tags: regex

I'm using the notation `L(a)` to denote a language - a set of strings, described by a regular expression `s`. For example `L(a)` is the set `{"a"}`.

The same way, using derivation rules to find the language for a regular expression I can do the following:

```
L(a(b|c)) => {ab, ac}
```

because

```
a(b|c) => a(b) = ab
```

and

```
a(b|c) => a(c) = ac
```

which I understand. But I can't come up with the derivations in the following example:

```
L((a|b)*) = ab
```

because

```
(a|b)*
  => (a|b)(a|b)*
  => a(a|b)*
  => a(a|b)(a|b)*
  => ab(a|b)*
  => ab
```

How's that the first step is `(a|b)(a|b)*`? Having defined `*` as:

> A concatenation of any number (including 0) of strings derived from
> *s*. The number depends on how many times the second rule is used:

```
s*        equals   s* =>
                   s* => s(s*)
```

Taken from [Springer, Introduction to Compiler Design, 2nd - 1.1 Regular expressions](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319669656)

Comment: I think such questions belong Comp Sci sites and not SO.

Comment: Are you sure that `L((a|b)*) = ab` is a correct result of a derivation? This language is clearly not made of the string `ab` alone, but it is `w in E*, where E={a,b}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that your example is correct (maybe there is a typo). The derivation rules of Brzozowski that you need are:

```
(1) L(a*)  = L(a)*
(2) L(a|b) = L(a) U L(b)
(3) L(a)   = {a}
```

Then you get:

```
L((a|b)*) = L(a|b)*         ; applying rule #1, note the Kleene star location
          = (L(a) U L(b))*  ; rule #2
          = ({a} U {b})*    ; rule #3, two times
          = ({a, b})*       ; combining into a single set
          = {a, b}*         ; removing the useless parentheses
```

Comment: I can tell Brzozowski Derivatives of regular expressions is mentioned through the chapter, but double checking the example given in the question I didn't spot any difference. I might check the errata, if any. This helps a lot, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. One think is for sure that `L(a*) = {e} U L(a+)`, where e is epsilon. Also the languages usually denote the sets with a letter and then it will become as I have written in the comment up: `w in E*, where E={a,b}`, as E is usually the sigma sign, and is the language alphabet.